# Embedding CIVICRM calendar extension output in a Drupal page

Tags: civievent

I have the event calendar extension installed in CIVICRM within a Drupal installation. It works fine, but I would like to be able to embed the calendar within a Drupal page, so that I can add preceding text as well as some content after it. I've tried using iFrames, but that includes all of the particular page including menus, headers, etc. and all I want to include is the calendar itself. I'm not sure whether I should be asking this here or in the Drupal forums, but thought I'd check here first.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I can't help you in terms of the extension - but [this blog](http://www.fuzion.co.nz/blogs/simple-view-showing-civi-events-calendar) tells you how do this directly with Views - and provides a starter one too.

Note you need the [CiviCRM Entities](http://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) module and of course the [Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) module

Happy Civi Day